# Does anyone have experience with modify the two-dimensional code project about zxing?

Tags: android, zxing

I'm modifying a two-dimensional code project which is based on an open source project zxing, but When I input Chinese characters, I found the results which get from the other two-dimensional code software always with "] Q2 \ 000026" prefix. I cann't understand what it means. Used zxing-2.1 version. Here is the project link http://code.google.com/p/zxing/.

My project code is:

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 try {
            mTextContent = chinese test 中文测试";
            Bitmap bitmap = Create2DCode(mTextContent);
            return;
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public Bitmap Create2DCode(String str) throws WriterException {
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object>();
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.Q);
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "GBK");//UTF-8
    // hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");//It's the same result.
    BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500, hints);
    int width = matrix.getWidth();
    int height = matrix.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = 0xffffffff;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (matrix.get(x, y)) {
                pixels[y * width + x] = 0xff000000;
            }
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Can anybody give me some help?

Comment: Have you tried other flavors of UTF? UTF16 for example?

Comment: Yes, I have tried UTF-8, it still exists this problem, and I get failed with UTF-16. I think this may be some problems with the support of the new version about the Chinese, because I observed that the old version does not appear this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the QR software you used may not support it. because I ever used zxing lib and wrote the code as below. Chinese can be recognized by the app named "wochacha", but not by "wechat"

Map hints = new HashMap();
     hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF8");
         BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400, hints);